# Angular ng-if ternary operator in one span?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

So am trying to use a ternary operator to combine 2 spans as:

```
<span ng-if="customer != null">{{ customer }}</span><span ng-if="customer == null">[customer]</span>
```

The switch is just based on if an id has a value or not in an input elsewhere in the form. Suggestions?

Thanks much.

Comment: are you looking for `ng-switch` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you mean something like:

```
<span>{{ (customer != null) ? customer : '[customer]' }}</span>
```

could also be written as:

```
<span>{{ customer || '[customer]' }}</span>
```